# A question in " Decoding with a q-ary hamming code"

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

I am taking a course in Coding theory this semester and classes are online so there is minimal contact with the instructor.

Consider the following line :Since Ham(r,q) is a perfect single error correcting code, the coset leaders other than 0 are exactly the vectors of weight 1.

> I am not able to understand why non -zero  the coset leaders  are exactly the vectors of weight 1?

Answer (score -1):

The q-ary Hamming code has $n=\frac{q^r-1}{q-1}$ and $k=\frac{q^r-1}{q-1}-r$. The ambient space $V(n,q)$ has $q^n$ elements, and $|\mathscr{C}|=q^k=q^{n-r}$. This implies that the number of cosets are $\frac{|V(n,q)|}{|\mathscr{C}|}=q^{n-k}=q^{r}$. However, notice that all the messages we can send of length $n$ are $n(q-1)=q^r-1$, and the codeword $(0,0, \ldots, 0)$, i.e., a total of $n+1=q^r$ codewords. Thus, all the vectors here have weight $1$ and are coset leaders.

Comment: This is on the right track, but it should be generalized for non-binary Hamming codes

Comment: @leonbloy Thank you so much for pointing it out! Hope these edits suffice. Do let me know if any further edits need to be made.

Comment: @Batrachotoxin "However, notice that all the messages we can send of length n are $n(q−1)=q^r−1$". Why number of messages is $q^r -1$? CAn you explain?

Comment: @Batrachotoxin Can you also have a look at this question?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229523/weight-of-every-codeword-in-g-24-is-a-multiple-of-4

Comment: @leonbloy Can you please have a look at this question if you got some time. It has a bounty on it